# SWIG template widhout node - it is possible to use it as standalone js library?

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, django-templates, swig-template

There are some great js template engine for Django programmers:
http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

But it is available in npn package for node.js.
And  render method require path to file:

```
swig.renderFile('/path/to/template.html', {
    pagename: 'awesome people',
    authors: ['Paul', 'Jim', 'Jane']
});
```

It is posible use it like others js/jquery librariers and render templates from string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the `render(source, options)` method.

```
var output = swig.render('{{ tacos }}', {
    locals: {
        tacos: 'Tacos!!!!'
    }
});
```

Unless you mean you want to run it in the browser, then take a look at the [documentation](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/browser/).

Comment: This file is also importan (not from repo):
http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/js/swig.min.js